# How to run multi module maven project on jetty?

Tags: java, spring, maven, jetty

I'm trying to make a multi module maven project with two modules: "listUsersRest" (using Spring REST) and "listUsersDomain" (using Spring Data JPA). The REST module has a dependency on domain, which is clarified in pom. My target is to build parent project and run it using "jetty:run". Project is built without any errors and warnings. However after the build, there no response on localhost:8080/listusers.

Here is parent pom:

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.vis</groupId>
<artifactId>listUsersParent</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>

<build>
    <finalName>dpr-data</finalName>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>9.3.0.M1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>
<modules>
    <module>listUsersDomain</module>
    <module>listUsersRest</module>
</modules>
```

Here is REST pom:

```
<parent>
        <groupId>com.vis</groupId>
        <artifactId>listUsersParent</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>listUsersRest</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>9.3.0.M1</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>

    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vis</groupId>
            <artifactId>listUsersDomain</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        ...
```

Here is REST controller:

```
@RestController
public class UserListController {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/userlist", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<User> userlist() {
        List<User> userList = userService.findAll();
        return userList;
    }
}
```

UserService is defined in domain.

Answer (score 0):

I would try like this:

1. `mvn clean package` on parent
2. `mvn jetty:run` on rest module

And try changing packaging in rest module to `war`

Comment: I have done the described sequence. However, after "mvn jetty:run" on rest module I got the following error:

015-03-20 13:52:32.406:INFO:/:main: Spring WebApplicationInitializers detected on classpath: WARN:oejuc.AbstractLifeCycle:main: FAILED org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.ServletContainerInitializersStarter@16c8b7bd: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/context/annotation/AnnotationConfigRegistry

What could be the probable problem?

Comment: not sure, can you edit the question and put full pom.xml files? all 3